# Is it okay to downvote a question for not knowing where to post it?

Tags: discussion

My question is not referring to blatantly posting some off topic questions (like Physics related or even Music related) into Stack Overflow but rather someone who didn't know where to post a similar-related question. I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070682/search-for-term-or-phrase-in-a-multiple-filesjava) where OP didn't really know about [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and posted her code into Stack Overflow thinking that that was the place where she can post her questions dealing with coding.

Now, I'm wondering if OP's negligence was something that's worth downvoting her for? I left a comment, directing her to codereview.stackexchange.com (which I'm almost positive she didn't know about) but others have downvoted her question. I know Stack Overflow can be both a welcoming as well as a hostile place for newbies but in this case, wouldn't it have been better for us to comment and leave it at that rather than downvoting so that she can learn the culture and different Stack Exchange sites without (exaggerting) punishing her?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to "is it okay to downvote [...]" is always yes. Use your downvotes as you see fit.

Comment: You should generally down-vote when the question isn't useful or lacks research effort. The latter might somewhat apply here, but to be honest there's nothing stopping you from down voting for anything else, including no reason at all.

Comment: Is the question useful to Stack Overflow users? No? Downvote. Yes...but off-topic? Close Vote

Comment: @Whymarrh the one exception is serial voting for/against a user.

Comment: Well I guess my question wasn't really of a "can you" but rather "should you". I understand that people can downvote anybody they choose to but for the future's sake, is this something that's acceptable to downvote rather than redirecting them through comments?

Comment: @Paulie_D, also couldn't this question of efficiency in searching a file for a specific phrase be useful to Stack Overflow users? I know that's where it's headed towards codereview but I feel like it's still a gray area.

Comment: Is it potentially useful...sure. I wouldn't have downvoted this one...although I would have close-voted. I tend to give the benefit of the doubt unless it's aggregiously unclear or lacking in research effort.

Comment: So.... maybe I'm pedantic here.... but if you do your research BEFORE you ask your question, you'll see that this should be on code-review. So yes, it's appropriate to downvote, as if you post on the wrong site, chances are you didn't do all your research<

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's entirely appropriate to downvote a question for being off topic, or otherwise not belonging on the site that it was posted on.

The fact that the person posting the question didn't know that their question doesn't belong where they posted it shouldn't in any way stop you from downvoting the post.  Your vote should reflect the quality of the post on the site, not the intentions of the author.

If you want to leave a comment when you downvote an inappropriate post, that's fine, but it's very important for you to actually downvote inappropriate content, for the sake of all potential future readers.  Not downvoting content that you know is bad is being extremely inconsiderate to all of those people.

Answer (score 5):

**SO users have a lot of latitude as to what standards they may want to apply to decide whether to downvote or upvote posts.** In the case at hand here you hypothesize that people perhaps downvoted the question because the OP did not know where to post it. While it is *possible* that some downvoted for this reason, there are other possible reasons. Some people are averse (with good reasons) to optimization for the sake of optimization. The question you refer to does not provide any context for the code shown in the question. Why should it be optimized? Moreover, generally speaking, optimizations are trade-offs. One solution will be best for data having such and such characteristics and another solution might be better for data having different characteristics. (For instance, searching through *ordered* data will call for a different solution than searching through data which is unordered.) The OP is silent about what characteristics the data possesses that may influence optimization. Without having a critical mass of details regarding the optimization task, the whole exercise turns into opinion.

The one limitation to the latitude we have in voting is that we don't allow serial downvoting (which means going after a user's posts and downvoting them one after another).

There are voting behaviors that we can *say* are not beneficial to the site. For instance, if you downvote an excellent post because you had a bad day and just have to take it on someone, this is not helpful to the site. If you do this and ask me whether what you've done is okay, I'm going to say no. However, neither moderators nor SO employees are in the business of reverting such votes. And what is considered harmful to the site varies from person to person. Some people downvote answers to bad questions even if the answer is otherwise good, other people think such downvotes are unwarranted. Again, the powers-that-be do not intervene (so long as it does not turn into serial voting).